# Importing classes from different module levels causes typehint and argument warning disabling

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path, sys

I have this file structure:

```
 - package
   - sub_package_1
     - __init__.py
     - sub_module_1.py
   - sub_package_2
     - __init__.py
     - sub_module_2.py
```

In `sub_module_1.py` we have this code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

    def method_a(self, var: int):
        pass


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method_b(self, var: int):
        pass



class C:  # This class always located in different module, but for example lets place it here
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def method_c(self, var: int):
        pass


a = A()
a.b.method_b()  # here we have an argument warning (method_b is waiting for an argument)

c = C()
c.a.b.method_b()  # and also here, the same warning
```

And in `sub_module_2.py` we have this code:

```
from package.sub_package_1.sub_module_1 import A


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def method_c(self, var: int):
        pass


c = C()
c.a.b.method_b()  # but here we don't have a warning
```

I've leaved some comments in code to show the problem.
When I work in the same module (or even in the same package), I can see all warnings, caused by methods' arguments. But if I move one of the classes outside the package (like I did with `C` class) I loose all warnings. I still can autocomplete lines, has typehinting etc, but I have no warnings in case I do not pass any argument in `c.a.b.method_b()`.

I feel like this is an import issue, but I can't find the solution.
What is the reason of this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As written, the inferred type of `c.a` is `Any`, which means you can do *anything* with it, and `mypy` (and likely other tools) will be happy. This includes assuming `c.a` has an attribute `b` with a 0-argument method `method_b`.

This is because you haven't provided any annotations for various `__init__` functions, which makes `mypy` essentially ignore them and anything they produce.

Provide explicit return types of `None` for the `__init__` methods, and you should get the expected error even across import boundaries.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def method_b(self, var: int):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added `-> None` annotation to every `__init__` in my classes. This truly solved this `c.a.method_a()` issue in `sub_module_2.py`. But `c.a.b.method_b()` in the same module still doesn't throw a warning.

Comment: I also found that if you change the directories (like adding some depth, where `sub_module_1`  is located one level lower), than even `c.a.method_a()` stops working. Look like it's also the import issue. But I still didn't find the solution.

Comment: I've found the problem. Updated the question with answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid my answer was a bit too minimal. Also, I'm not aware of anything PyCharm specific, as I don't use it myself. But in general, most type-checking problems can be solved by adding more type hints :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one wise man for his help, he pointed his finger at the mistake.

The problem (not actually the problem, just IDE optimisation) is that **PyCharm has a depth checking limit**, which can be configured, but this can cause really heavy lags, so this is not a solution.

The real one is to try **not to forget typehint** every single line of code. In this current case, we need to do this in `sub_module_2.py`:

```
from package.sub_package_1.sub_module_1 import A


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a: A = A()  # Here I forgot to typehint the class
    ...
```

But much better is to make a typehint at the class level, rather than in the `__init__` method, bc on some depth of 'checking-levels' PyCharm stops checking `__init__` methods (for the sake of optimization, and that makes sense).

So, if we want to make linter not lose any warning and typehint from nested callings, we need to **put the typing in class level**, like this:

```
from package.sub_package_1.sub_module_1 import A


class C:
    """
    So, even if this class call is too deep, 
    PyCharm will check class (as minimum) and spot the `a: A` hint at class level.
    That would not have happened, if hint was in the `__init__` method.
    """

    a: A  # Here is the feature

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
    ...
```